# Finding non-monotonic regions in decision trees

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have a binary decision tree T that takes a vector V of n real numbers, and outputs a number S by following per coordinate binary splits on V.  I'd like to find regions of the tree that are non-monotonic.  That is, if I decrease one more more inputs in V to form V' and the tree then assigns a larger output to V' than to V, then I've found a non-monotonic region.

How can find these regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that "per coordinate binary splits" means that decisions are made on a single coordinate at a time. For all pairs of leaves L1 and L2 where L1 has lower value than L2, determine the axis-aligned bounding boxes for L1 and L2. If L1's maximum corner dominates L2's minimum corner for some L1 and L2, then the tree is non-monotone. Conversely, if no such pair exists, then the tree is monotone.

Comment: Nice.  With a coworker, we came up with the enumerate all pairs of leaves solution as well.  Is there a better than O(leaves^2) solution?

Comment: @rrenaud Asymptotically speaking? Undoubtedly. The question is which ranges of n and #leaves you actually care about.

Comment: @rrenaud To expand a little bit on that comment, I think this can be done with O(log n) calls (maybe even O(1)) to a subroutine that determines whether a set of points in n dimensions has an empty dominance relation, which is easier than the n-dimensional maxima problem, for which there exist sub-quadratic algorithms for fixed n. The problem is that the latter suffer from the curse of dimensionality.

Comment: n is small, right now ~=10, conceivably it could go up to 50 (these correspond to hand engineered features).  I am not sure about num leaves, right now it's less than 25k (number of training points), but can grow much easier.

Comment: @rrenaud Back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests that the theoretical best algorithms for maxima won't be useful to you. There might be some improvement available in how you enumerate candidate pairs of leaves (e.g., store subtree mins/maxes; loop over all leaves and, in enumerating the possibilities for the other leaf, prune the subtrees where it's obvious that there are no interesting possibilities).

Answer (score 0):

I am not providing particulars, just the general direction. let me know if you need more details.

Assume you have a tree that considers a single feature (i.e. one real number) and outputs either one single number or a range. Now, it is straightforward to find non-monotonic regions of that tree (at any node, if the range of the left subtree overlaps the range of the right subtree, then there are non-monotonic regions in that part of the tree).

You can convert your general DT into a DT that works on only one feature and apply the above methodology.

In general you can maintain the range for each feature at every node and use the same criteria I mention above to find such regions.

Comment: I don't see the general DT -> single feature DT construction.  Fundamentally, even a 2D DT has regions that are incomparable (neither dominates each other in the V, V' sense from the OP), where as all regions in a 1 feature DT are comparable.